# Android Studio Gradle Distrubution Doesn't Exist

Tags: android-studio, gradle

"*The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip' does not exist.*"

Everytime I open the Android Studio I see this error message. But the funny thing is when I check the gradle 7.0.2 version, this is already installed in my computer.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST5j6.png)

So I don't understand why this error message still there. Is there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can see right versions here:
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem. It solved with remove gradle 7.0.2 folder and download it again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).